# Animations in lists with item-remove-animate

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm having troubles finding the documentation for the command 
`item-remove-animate` in Ionic. The code I am studying uses it as a class on a list item and the animation simply works its magic. Code:

```
<ion-item class= "item-remove-animate item-icon-right item>
      <p>Some content</p>
</ion-item>
```

Is there a more animations available like `item-add-animate` for example?

Comment: this tutorial here looks really informative: http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-animate-your-ionic-app-with-animate-css-and-nganimate/
Also it states that you must download the animate.css file and include it in your index.html.